# Query: count items under an object MongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

If my db is the following, how can I count the number of movies in total?
I want an output like that

**N_Movies: 3**

I was searching online but couldn't find a way to do that.

I really appreciate your help!

```html
"Movies": 
              [ 
              { "Date": "15/01/2016", 
                "Time": "00:57:00", 
                "Title": "Resident Evil", 
                "License": { "Date": "15/01/2016", "Time": "00:00:00"}, 
         
                "Viewing PCT": 99
              },
              { "Date": "22/01/2016", 
                "Time": "22:01:00", 
                "Title": "Whatever It Takes", 
                "License": { "Date": "22/01/2016", "Time": "00:00:00"}, 
               
                "Viewing PCT": 1
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you are trying to find the size of the array. You can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of aggregation to get the size of array

```
db.aggregate([{'$project':{'N_Movies':{'$size':'$Movies'}}}])
```

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't work as "The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: String"